# Why do <div> tags appear in FMX Memo Component when being populated from Microsoft Access Long Text Field?

Tags: ms-access, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria, memo

For a school task, I need to display certain news articles about the climate in a Delphi FireMonkey Form. I have a Long Text field that contains the article's body in Microsoft Access.

When I try to populate a Memo component on my Delphi FMX form from the Access database,  tags appear everywhere. (See Image). Is there anything I can do to fix this? Thanks.

[image: Populated FMX Memo Component with the Article's body, showing tags.]

[image: Long Text "Article_Body" field in Microsoft Access.]

Comment: Using the StringReplace replace function is a solution to this problem.

Comment: Where are the news texts from? How have they been inserted in the access DB?

Answer (score 0):

The Long Text field(s) in your Access DB have a property called `TextFormat` which is obviously set to `RichText`. Change that (in Access) to `PlainText`, then you should also see the `<div>` tags in Access where you can delete them from the field content, so they don't appear in the Delphi app anymore.